# What does this Controller Instantiation exception mean?

Tags: scala, playframework

I'm getting the following error at runtime:

```
java.lang.InstantiationException: controllers.ApplicationController
at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:418) ~[na:1.8.0_11]
at play.api.GlobalSettings$class.getControllerInstance(GlobalSettings.scala:198) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
at play.api.DefaultGlobal$.getControllerInstance(GlobalSettings.scala:206) ~[play_2.11-2.3.7.jar:2.3.7]
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$43.apply(routes_routing.scala:198) ~[na:na]
at Routes$$anonfun$routes$1$$anonfun$applyOrElse$1$$anonfun$apply$43.apply(routes_routing.scala:198) ~[na:na]
Caused by: java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: controllers.ApplicationController.<init>()
```

I've been looking for a few weeks for suspicious differences between my app and [a working seed app](https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-seed/tree/master/app), but I can't find any. My application controller looks like:

```
class ApplicationController @Inject() (implicit val env: Environment[User, SessionAuthenticator]) extends Silhouette[User, SessionAuthenticator] { ... }
```

My routes look the same as the seed app's, very simple:

```
GET         /                                      @controllers.ApplicationController.index
```

Does anything come to mind? What should I be looking at? I've been stumped for a while on this, I know it's a terrible question but I have no other option at this point. The error message doesn't seem to indicate anything useful, unfortunately. I still don't miss Rails.

Answer (score 4):

I can guess that you're comparing this to the Silhouette Seed. The Silhouette Seed uses Guice to instantiate the controllers.

This needs to be configured in a custom Global object. See here

https://github.com/mohiva/play-silhouette-seed/blob/master/app/Global.scala

The critical line is

```
override def getControllerInstance[A](controllerClass: Class[A]) = injector.getInstance(controllerClass)
```

which is executed when you route file defines the controller as an instatiable class by preceding the controller with '@' in the routes.conf.

If your Global.scala file is not in the default package you need to configure it in the application.conf file with the property "application.global".

e.g.

```
application.global=app.Global
```